# How to generate moc_*.cpp files using CMake

Tags: c++, qt, moc

Suppose I have a C++ file named `animals.cpp`. How can I generate a moc file (`moc_animals.cpp`) using CMake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways. if you are using CMAKE version grater than 2.8.6 then you can use [AUTOMOC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) which should do everything automatically for you.

Here there is a nice [tutorial](https://blogs.kde.org/2011/11/01/cool-new-stuff-cmake-286-automoc).

As pointed out by @spectras this assumes respecting their naming convention. If you want to use your specific naming  you can of course use the manual mechanism by simple calling `qt4_wrap_cpp` or `qt5_wrap_cpp`. This is also what you should do in case you are bound to older CMAKE versions.

Comment: This is the correct way, if you follow the nomenclature that comes with it. If you don't for some reason, you may still resort to manual `qt4_wrap_cpp` or `qt5_wrap_cpp`.

Comment: yes... I will add your comment to my answer then... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the bin directory of your Qt installation there is the moc command.

/Users/name/Qt 5.7/...../bin

If you add it with execute_process() or add_custom_command() you should be able to do what you intend to do. You can use [AUTOMOC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) too